# Is it possible to pass time in milliseconds in tdl(tally Definition Language) proprietary language?

Tags: tdl

I have a datetime in mm-dd-yyy hh:mm:ss format. I want to convert into milliseconds in TDL. is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

you will have to create a function for this.